# sqlite3 file corrupted after compressing

Tags: python, sqlite

After I finished working with my db file 
I tried to make it tar file but before that I saw the size of db file it was 3 MB. After I compressed it to tar file the original file turned to 10 KB and the compressed file too turned to 10 KB.

This is the command I used to compress the file:

```
tar cf users.db /root/Desktop/users.tar
```

I don't know whats happen but in properties of file turned to
"STL 3D model (binary) (model/x.stl-binary) " it supposed be 
"SQLite3 database (application/x-sqlite3)"

I tried to use .dump in sqlite3 but nothing fixed it shows the following error:

```
/**** ERROR: (26) file is not a database *****/
```

Comment: your question is unclear. Are you saying that _after decompression_, the resulting file is corrupted? What command did you use to "compress it to tar file"?

Comment: i used " tar cf users.db /root/Desktop/users.tar "

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments to the `tar` command were incorrect.  The syntax is:

```
tar cf <archive to create> <files to add to the archive>
```

Because you put `users.db` in the `<archive to create>` position, you have replaced your `users.db` file with an empty `tar` archive.  Unless you have a backup of your database, it's gone.

Comment: i realized that after i did it :/

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you wrote that you did this command:

```
tar cf users.db /root/Desktop/users.tar
```

When you use the `f` option for tar, the *next argument* specifies the file *to be created*. What you did was to archive an existing file (/root/Desktop/users.tar), and *overwrite* users.db.

Whatever was in users.db has been destroyed after running that command.

Comment: please don't say 
is there is any try left to do :/